# Thymeleaf operation perform concat instead of multiply

Tags: java, spring-boot, math, thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf template with a java project but noticed a weird result when performing the following arithmetic operation on some variables:

```
<div th:with="p=${(a.num != null ? a.num[0] : 1 ) * #list.size(b.items)}">
  <p th:inline="text">[[${p}]] of [[#list.size(b.items)]] items</p>
</div>
```

Given a.num == null, and b.items contains 20, my expected result is:

```
20 of 20 items
```

But currently it shows like this instead:

```
11111111111111111111 of 20 items
```

It seems to read 1 as string and concat it 20 times. How can I make it perform multiplication instead?

I'm not well versed with thymeleaf and its my first time handling this project so I'd rather not change the value on the service layer and just perform this simple multiplication on the view layer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both have to be numbers to be able to perform the multiplication.

- `${'3' * 4}` - will result in 3333
- `${3 * 4 }` - will result in 12
- `${#conversions.convert('3', 'java.lang.Integer') * 4}` will result in 12. Here we are converting `java.lang.String` to `java.lang.Integer`